# Calling showInformationMessage in VSCode extension not working

Tags: vscode-extensions

In my VSCode extension, I'm calling `vscode.window.showInformationMessage()` to show a message to user. However, the message doesn't appear at all. If I pass in the `model` flag to true, it does show the modal dialog.

`vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Do you want to continue', { modal: true, detail: 'Something' }, 'Yes', 'No');`

I don't want the dialog to be modal though. Am I missing something? Why doesn't the non-modal mode work?

Comment: And you are not in zen mode?  Does it work as expected using `showErroeMessage()`? Does an `await` before the call make any difference.  "Note that detail is only shown for modal messages." so does removing both modal and detail make any difference?

Comment: I'm not in zen mode. If I change to `showErrorMessage()`, it does show up. But for the life of me, I can't get it work with `showInformationMessage()`. I'm calling it without the 'options' parameter. Just the string.

Comment: Hmm, there seems to be a problem with this machine of mine. I tried testing the exact same code on another machine and it worked. No idea why. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, there seems to be a problem with this machine of mine. I tried testing the exact same code on another machine and it worked. No idea why. :-